# Analytic functions $|f|\leq |g|$ on $\partial D$, then $|f|\leq|g|$ in $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Analytic functions $|f|\leq |g|$ on $\partial D$, then $|f|\leq|g|$ in
>   $D$.

Suppose $D$ is just the unit disk, is this statement true? I am learning about Schwarz Lemma, and I can not find a good counter example to the above statement.

I also know that if $|f|<|g|$ on $\partial D$, then by Rouche's theorem, $f+g$ and $g$ would have the same number of zeros, but this is not very helpful.

Comment: This is false: note that $|z| \le |z^2|$ on the unit circle, but $|z^2| < |z|$ whenever $|z| >0$ is sufficiently small. See Rouche's theorem for an example of what we can say when $|g| < |f|$ on $\partial D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true; for instance, take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}2$.

What should concern you about the statement you have is that it implies that, whenever $f$ has a root, so does $g$. The example I give here exploits that by taking $g$ to be small, but have no roots, and $f$ to have a root somewhere, but be large on the unit disk.